# ActionBarSherlock - SearchView is null?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, classnotfoundexception, searchview

I am adding Search functionality to Action Bar in a SherlockListActivity however, when I try to instantiate SearchView its always null:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.activity_main_menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String p1){
                List<Application> auxList = Search.search(mContext, p1);
                AdapterApp aux = new AdapterApp(mContext, auxList);
                setListAdapter(aux);
                getListView().setOnItemClickListener(aux.getItemClickListener());
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String p1){
                return false;
            }           
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

activity_main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView " />

    <item android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu_purchase"
        android:title="@string/purchase"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_market_holo"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

Also I have to say that I have correctly imported required classes:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
```

And this is stack trace. When SearchView is instantiated, log returns this:

```
06-03 19:42:43.128: W/dalvikvm(15936): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView '
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936): Cannot instantiate class: com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView 
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView " on path: /data/app/com.iamaner.oneclickfreeze-1.apk
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:486)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:447)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:468)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:190)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:112)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.iamaner.oneclickfreeze.ActivityMain.onCreateOptionsMenu(ActivityMain.java:131)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockListActivity.java:184)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:559)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:65)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SherlockListActivity.java:149)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:458)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:820)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:248)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5231)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 19:42:43.138: W/MenuInflater(15936):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
```

Then, SearchView is null, so I get a NullPointerException when calling SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener();

```
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at com.iamaner.oneclickfreeze.ActivityMain.onCreateOptionsMenu(ActivityMain.java:133)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockListActivity.java:184)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:559)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:65)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SherlockListActivity.java:149)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:458)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:820)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:248)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5231)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 19:42:43.148: E/AndroidRuntime(15936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
```

I have wasted all a day searching the cause of the error, but no success... Please I need help

Comment: On which Android version is happening that and which theme you have set as your default?

Comment: well i set target sdk to 17 and min sdk to 8. however i found the error: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685 . The comment posted  here was my solution: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685#issuecomment-11670533

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the error itself is caused by ActionBarSherlock library, you can find the issue in GitHub here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685

And the comment posted  here was my solution: 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685#issuecomment-11670533

Go to res/values-v14/abs_themes.xml of ABS library project: then you should edit first two themes like this:

```
<style name="Sherlock.__Theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="Sherlock.__Theme.Light" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

Also dont forget to declare in your manifest for those activities which use it:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really familiar with the usage of the ActionBarSherlock SearchView class, but I can tell you is that if you look at the [samples](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/SearchViews.java), he doesn't try to get the SearchView from the menu, but rather he creates the SearchView and **sets** it to the menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    boolean isLight = SampleList.THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

    //Create the search view
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search for countries…");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);

    if (mSuggestionsAdapter == null) {
        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);
        cursor.addRow(new String[]{"1", "'Murica"});
        cursor.addRow(new String[]{"2", "Canada"});
        cursor.addRow(new String[]{"3", "Denmark"});
        mSuggestionsAdapter = new SuggestionsAdapter(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), cursor);
    }

    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mSuggestionsAdapter);

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: well all that seemed to be innecessary... i found the error: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685 . The comment posted  here was my solution: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685#issuecomment-11670533 . Thanks for the answer, vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685#issuecomment-12947636) on the above mentioned github issue solved it form me.  (Strange fix, as you just remove Theme's base.)